# Two android ViewPagers in the fragment backstack are not coming up properly after activity is recreated

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment-backstack

My Android app has only one activity and all the fragments are added or replaced in one framelayout.

The issue is when I have two different viewpagers in the fragment backstack and the activity is recreated the second viewpager comes up as the first viewpager.

Below is how I add the fragments to the backstack in the order that they happen so 3 is the fragment that comes up after the activity is recreated.

1. setupPlacesEventMainView(), this is a viewpager which uses a FragmentStatePagerAdapter.(shows up properly after activity is recreated)
2. setupPlaceDetailViewPager, this is a viewpager which uses a FragmentStatePagerAdapter. (**ISSUE:** PlacesEventMainViewPager shows up here instead of PlaceDetailViewPager. The issue occurs even if I  don't navigate into the EventSpecials)
3. setupEventSpecials(), this is a listfragment. (shows up properly after activity is recreated)

**Add PlacesEventMainViewPager to backstack**

```
public void setupPlacesEventMainView()
{
    clearBackStack();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    PlacesEventMainViewPager placesEventMainViewPager = new PlacesEventMainViewPager();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, placesEventMainViewPager, PlacesEventMainViewPager.class.getSimpleName());
    transaction.commit();
}
```

**Add PlaceDetailViewPager to backstack**

```
 public void setupPlaceDetailViewPager(Event event) {


    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    PlaceDetailViewPager placeDetailViewPager = new PlaceDetailViewPager();
    placeDetailViewPager.setEvent(event);
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, placeDetailViewPager,PlaceDetailViewPager.class.getSimpleName());
    transaction.addToBackStack(PlaceDetailViewPager.class.getSimpleName());
    transaction.commit();
}
```

**Add SpecialsList to backstack**

```
    public void setupEventSpecials(Agenda[] agendas) {

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    SpecialsList specialsList = new SpecialsList();
    specialsList.setAgendas(agendas);
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, specialsList,SpecialsList.class.getSimpleName());
    transaction.addToBackStack(SpecialsList.class.getSimpleName());
    transaction.commit();
}
```

What the fragments contain.

- PlacesEventMainViewPager contains 3 listfragments.
- PlaceDetailViewPager contains 2 listfragments
- SpecialsList is 1 listfragment.

I can reach the PlaceDetailViewPager fragment by clicking on one of the items in the PlacesEventMainViewPager fragment. I can reach the SpecialsList by clicking a button in the PlaceDetailViewPager fragment.

Please let me know if you need any more details. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never add PlacesEventMainViewPager to the backstack which makes PlaceDetailViewPager the first one in the backstack if you listed them in order.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!  This has been bothering me for a while.  I hit the upvote but don't have a reputation of 15.